# New windows mobile project - LINQ to data in .NET CF?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I have to convert a project I wrote a while back in MCL to windows mobile using CF 3.5. I am using Visual Basic and VS 2008. There is not much info out there, and much of what is, is in C#.  I am working my way through that right now.

What is the best way for data access?  I am used to using LINQ to SQL, but that does not seem to be a option. I need to be able to do searches for data that meet criteria, normal CRUD operations, etc.

I have spent days researching this and have come across **so** much conflicting data! This project needs to be finished in the next 3 weeks or so. I am pretty pressured right about now.

All your thoughts are sincerely appreciated!

--Joe

Comment: Clarification:
Your right, Henk - more data would be good:

-I am planning on using sqlce on the device
-the devices are symbol mc-70 and symbol mc-9060's
-The device will sync up daily to upload the days data
-The app is a package tracking, signautre capture system like UPS uses
-The data import is handled by a vb.net app running on a windows server that hits a sql 2008 database
-Like I said, mostly looking for guidence as far as how to to data access -- guides etc... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a question like "what is the best way for data access" is rather vague. 
You may want to be a bit more specific on your needs and especially what database you intend to use or whether tat is still open.

Having said that, SqlCE with typed or untyped Datasets and/or direct Commands is solidly supported. There are also options to hook that into the sync framework.

---

To add a little more info, there is a SqlCeResultset that is more efficient (memory wise) than a regular Dataset. Make sure to investigate that option.

In short: create a normal typed dataset first, then find the properties of the XSD file and change Custom_Tool to  MSResultSetGenerator

Concerning the uploading,  forget RDA. Take a look at the Patterns&Practices Disconnected Service Agent or the [Sync Services for ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx)

Comment: Clarification: Your right, Henk - more data would be good: -I am planning on using sqlce on the device -the devices are symbol mc-70 and symbol mc-9060's -The device will sync up daily to upload the days data -The app is a package tracking, signautre capture system like UPS uses -The data import is handled by a vb.net app running on a windows server that hits a sql 2008 database -Like I said, mostly looking for guidence as far as how to to data access -- guides etc... Thanks!

Comment: Thank you,

I am also working my way through this excelent ebook:
http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590590959

--Joe